# URL Rewrite Reverse Proxy on IIS only working on the server its self

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, gitea

I'm currently trying to set up a Gitea server on my Windows server 2016 standard server with Plesk installed. I have a subdomain setup which is git.thetofushop.net and I'm trying to make a Reverse proxy to point to the Gitea server which runs on port 3000.

this is my web.config for the subdomain

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://149.56.184.96:3000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But this only works internally on the server itself, it is not working outside of the server. You can visit the IP and port, but the reverse proxy point blank refuses to work. Now I'm not super adept with IIS, but I've tried what I can figure out from what I've found. If someone can give me a reason and an exact steps to fix this id. I am also open at this point to allowing someone to TeamViewer in and fix it as I've been trying to figure this out for 8 straight hours.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed ARR and enable its proxy mode?

Comment: i have arr installed but i don't understand how to set it up I've tried fiddling with it to no avail ive tried following guides but im clearly making a mistake somewhere ive tried creating server farm to enable to proxy and stuff but if i enable to the proxy in server farms its brakes it on a local browser with just url rewrite for reverse proxy enable on the site it works locally btu not remotely if i try and add a server farm for the site it brakes it all it wont even work locally